How can i clear api's response cache after logout while using angular service worker?
I cache api's responses by using angular generated service worker , now i want to clear these caches after user decide to logout for this i made new custom service worker file which listens to messages from angular app and after that will try to clear the cache, but for checking when i put browser to offline mode and refresh the page i can still see that cached data, now i have question how can i clear them compeletly?
Here is my custom servcie worker:
importScripts('./ngsw-worker.js')
self.addEventListener('message', async event => {
    const cacheNames = await self.caches.keys()
    for (let name of cacheNames) {
         await self.caches.delete(name)
    }
    console.log('All caches deleted.')
})



First, create a custom service worker that extends Angular's NGSW worker:

importScripts('./ngsw-worker.js');

// Extend the NGSW worker
const ngsw = self;
const cacheNamePrefix = 'ngsw:';

self.addEventListener('install', (event) => {
  self.skipWaiting();
});

self.addEventListener('activate', (event) => {
  event.waitUntil(self.clients.claim());
});

self.addEventListener('message', async (event) => {
  if (event.data && event.data.type === 'CLEAR_CACHE') {
    try {
      // Clear all caches
      const cachesToDelete = await self.caches.keys();
      const deletionPromises = cachesToDelete.map(async (cacheName) => {
        try {
          await self.caches.delete(cacheName);
          console.log(`Cache ${cacheName} deleted successfully`);
        } catch (err) {
          console.error(`Failed to delete cache ${cacheName}:`, err);
        }
      });
      
      await Promise.all(deletionPromises);

      // Clear IndexedDB storage
      const databases = await self.indexedDB.databases();
      databases.forEach(async (db) => {
        if (db.name) {
          try {
            await self.indexedDB.deleteDatabase(db.name);
            console.log(`IndexedDB ${db.name} deleted successfully`);
          } catch (err) {
            console.error(`Failed to delete IndexedDB ${db.name}:`, err);
          }
        }
      });

      // Unregister the service worker itself
      const registrations = await self.registration.getRegistrations();
      await Promise.all(registrations.map(registration => registration.unregister()));

      console.log('Cache clearing completed');
      
      // Notify the client that cache clearing is complete
      event.source?.postMessage({
        type: 'CACHE_CLEARED',
        success: true
      });
    } catch (error) {
      console.error('Error during cache clearing:', error);
      event.source?.postMessage({
        type: 'CACHE_CLEARED',
        success: false,
        error: error.message
      });
    }
  }
});


Create an Angular service to handle the cache clearing:

import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { SwUpdate } from '@angular/service-worker';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class CacheService {
  constructor(private swUpdate: SwUpdate) {}

  async clearCache(): Promise<boolean> {
    if (!this.swUpdate.isEnabled) {
      console.warn('Service Worker is not enabled');
      return false;
    }

    return new Promise((resolve) => {
      // Listen for the response from the Service Worker
      navigator.serviceWorker.addEventListener('message', (event) => {
        if (event.data && event.data.type === 'CACHE_CLEARED') {
          resolve(event.data.success);
        }
      });

      // Send message to Service Worker
      if (navigator.serviceWorker.controller) {
        navigator.serviceWorker.controller.postMessage({
          type: 'CLEAR_CACHE'
        });
      } else {
        console.warn('No Service Worker controller found');
        resolve(false);
      }
    });
  }
}


Use the cache service in your logout component/service:

import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { CacheService } from './cache.service';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class AuthService {
  constructor(
    private cacheService: CacheService,
    private router: Router
  ) {}

  async logout(): Promise<void> {
    try {
      // Clear all authentication data
      localStorage.clear();
      sessionStorage.clear();

      // Clear the service worker cache
      const cacheCleared = await this.cacheService.clearCache();
      
      if (cacheCleared) {
        console.log('Cache cleared successfully');
      } else {
        console.warn('Cache clearing may not have been completely successful');
      }

      // Force reload the application to ensure clean state
      window.location.href = '/login';
    } catch (error) {
      console.error('Error during logout:', error);
      // Handle error appropriately
    }
  }
}


Update your ngsw-config.json to ensure proper cache configuration:

{
  "$schema": "./node_modules/@angular/service-worker/config/schema.json",
  "index": "/index.html",
  "assetGroups": [
    {
      "name": "app",
      "installMode": "prefetch",
      "resources": {
        "files": [
          "/favicon.ico",
          "/index.html",
          "/manifest.webmanifest",
          "/*.css",
          "/*.js"
        ]
      }
    }
  ],
  "dataGroups": [
    {
      "name": "api-cache",
      "urls": [
        "/api/**"
      ],
      "cacheConfig": {
        "strategy": "freshness",
        "maxSize": 100,
        "maxAge": "3d",
        "timeout": "10s"
      }
    }
  ]
}


Finally, ensure your angular.json has the correct service worker configuration:

{
  "projects": {
    "your-app": {
      "architect": {
        "build": {
          "options": {
            "serviceWorker": true,
            "ngswConfigPath": "ngsw-config.json"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}


Clears all caches including Angular's service worker caches
Cleans up IndexedDB storage
Unregisters the service worker
Provides feedback about the cache clearing process
Forces a page reload to ensure a clean state


thanks for the response, but are you sure this will work? i tried it but it didnt work i will load app then i will put my application to offline mode and after sending CLEAR_CACHE message by loading page still i can see my data which means deleting cache didnt work properly, could you help me more aboout it?

code updated can you please check

this can work but i saw in your code you did unregistration for existing SW this is not a proper solution because it can cause some
